# Rename files depending on their parent directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I have a main directory, let's say `main`. This main directory has some folders, among which are three folders named `ccc` `ddd` and `lll`, which are the only folders I want to target and work on. Each of these subfolders has some folders inside which are all named the same in the three subfolders, so that `ccc` `ddd` `lll` subfolders contain folders of the same name.

Then, each of these subsubfolders that are inside `ccc` `ddd` `lll` has a number of files named with a certain name like this `c_000` `d_000` `l_000`, `c_001` `d_001` `l_001` and so on.

What I want to do first is rename these files so that the directory of their two parents will be attached in the beginning of the file name like this `ccc_foo1_c_000` `ddd_foo1_d_000` `lll_foo1_l_000` and so on. I'm asking if anyone can advise me how this can be done in a `.sh` script?

This is a simple tree structure of my main folder:

```
.
`-- main
    |-- ccc
    |   `-- foO1
    |   |    |-- c_000
    |   |    `-- c_001
    |   |
         -- foo2
    |       |-- c_000
    |       `-- c_001
    |   
    |   
    |-- ddd
    |   `-- foO1
    |   |    |-- d_000
    |   |    `-- d_001
    |   |
         -- foo2
    |       |-- d_000
    |       `-- d_001
    |-- lll
    |      `-- foO1
    |  |    |-- l_000
    |  |    `-- l_001
    |  |
    |   -- foo2
    |      |-- l_000
    |      `-- l_001
    |
    |-- aaa
    |-- bbb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for dir in ccc ddd lll; do 
    find "main/$dir" -type f -print0 | 
        while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
            dd=$(dirname "$f")
            new="${f/main\/}"
            new="${new//\//_}" 
            mv "$f" "$dd"/"$new"
        done
done
```

After the above script, your files will look like this:

```
.
`-- main
    |-- ccc
    |   |-- fo01
    |   |   |-- ccc_fo01_c_000
    |   |   `-- ccc_fo01_c_001
    |   `-- fo02
    |       |-- ccc_fo02_c_000
    |       `-- ccc_fo02_c_001
    |-- ddd
    |   |-- fo01
    |   |   |-- ddd_fo01_d_000
    |   |   `-- ddd_fo01_d_001
    |   `-- fo02
    |       |-- ddd_fo02_d_000
    |       `-- ddd_fo02_d_001
    `-- lll
        |-- fo01
        |   |-- lll_fo01_l_000
        |   `-- lll_fo01_l_001
        `-- fo02
            |-- lll_fo02_l_000
            `-- lll_fo02_l_001
```

#### Explanation

- `for dir in ccc ddd lll; do ...; done` : do this only for these three directory names, saving each of them as `$dir`.
- `find "main/$dir" -type f -print0 |` : find all files (`type f`) in `main/$dir`, and print them separated by the null string (`-print0`) to ensure that it works even if your file/directory names contain newlines.
- `while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do` : this will iterate over the results of `find`, saving each as `$f`. The `IFS=` is needed to avoid breaking on whitespace, the `-r` is so that backslashes are not treated specially and the `-d ''` allows the reading of null-delimited input.
- `dd=$(dirname "$f")` : `$dd` is now the directory where the current file resides. For example, `main/ccc/fo01`.
- `new="${f/main\/}"` : this is using the shell's [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) abilities to remove the string `main/` from the file's path.
- `new="${new//\//_}"` : as above only now we are replacing all `/` with underscores. This results in a string like `ccc_fo01_c000`.
- `mv "$f" "$dd"/"$new"` : finally, we rename the original file `$f` to `$dd/$new`. Remember that `$dd` is the directory this file was found in and `$new` is now the name you want to rename it to.

**I suggest you add an `echo` before the `mv` to test before actually doing this.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Did you have the chance to check the second part of the question? regarding copying depending on the names of the files manually copied.

Comment: @shepherd please post that as a separate question.

Comment: no worries. Done :) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189833/copy-files-that-partially-matches-another-files-in-another-location

Comment: `find` is overly complex here, given that the directory structure has fixed depth. Even keeping `find` involved, you could simplify by calling `find ccc ddd lll …` instead of first looping over the toplevel directories.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple POSIX shell solution that loops over the files, parses the directory parts of the names and renames them one by one.

```
for x in ccc/*/* ddd/*/* lll/*/*; do
  dir2=${x%/*}; dir1=${dir2%/*}; dir2=${dir2#"$dir1"}
  mv -- "$x" "${x%/*}/${dir1}_${dir2}_${x##*/}"
done
```

In bash, you can use the [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) string replacement feature to avoid having to parse the file names.

```
for x in ccc/*/* ddd/*/* lll/*/*; do
  mv -- "$x" "${x%/*}/${x//\//_}"
done
```

In zsh, you can use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) to rename files based on patterns.

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '(ccc|ddd|lll)/(*)/(*)' '$1/$2/${1}_${2}_$3'
```

Answer (score 1):

For a somewhat more soft-coded solution run from within your directory `main`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(find . -name '*_00*'); do
    mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(dirname "${f:2}" | tr "/" "_")_$(basename $f)"
done
```

This should iterate through all directories recursively looking for all files containing the pattern `*_00*`. Each of this files is renamed separately with a combination consisting of the path (`$(dirname $"f")`), the transformed path containing underscores and the first two characters removed (`$(dirname "${f:2}" | tr "/" "_")`) and the original filename itself (`$(basename $f)`).

Comment: (1) When I see “`c_000`, `c_001`, and so on”, I assume that “and so on” can continue to `c_009`, `c_010`, ..., `c_042`, ..., `c_099`, `c_100`, ....  Your `*_00*` pattern won’t match those names (beyond `c_009`).  (And consider using `[cdl]_`....)  (2) This answer will process the `aaa` and `bbb` directories (i.e., it’s not restricted to `ccc`, `ddd` and `lll`).  (3) Good job, putting `$f` in quotes three times.  But why do you leave it unquoted the fourth time? (4) See [Why is looping over find’s output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/23408)