# Copy files that partially matches another files in another location

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, scripting, rename

I have a list of jpeg files in a directory like this (below is just a sample, like the structure is the same but this there are many `fo0#` sub-folders, not only `fo01` and `fo01`, where each of these subfolders has many `.jpeg` images, not only two):

```
.
`-- main
    |-- ccc
    |   |-- fo01
    |   |   |-- ccc_fo01_c_000.jpeg
    |   |   `-- ccc_fo01_c_001.jpeg
    |   `-- fo02
    |       |-- ccc_fo02_c_000.jpeg
    |       `-- ccc_fo02_c_001.jpeg
    |-- ddd
    |   |-- fo01
    |   |   |-- ddd_fo01_d_000.jpeg
    |   |   `-- ddd_fo01_d_001.jpeg
    |   `-- fo02
    |       |-- ddd_fo02_d_000.jpeg
    |       `-- ddd_fo02_d_001.jpeg
    `-- lll
        |-- fo01
        |   |-- lll_fo01_l_000.jpeg
        |   `-- lll_fo01_l_001.jpeg
        `-- fo02
            |-- lll_fo02_l_000.jpeg
            `-- lll_fo02_l_001.jpeg
```

some of the renamed `ccc_foo#_c_###` will be manually copied to the `ccc` directory. What I want to do is to check these manually copied files and then copy the equivalent `d_foo#_d_###` and `lll_foo#_l_###` in the `ddd` and `lll` directories respectively. For example if I copied `ccc_fo01_c_001.jpeg` and `ccc_fo02_c_000.jpeg` to the `ccc` folder, then my script should copy:

- `ddd_fo01_d_001.jpeg` and `ddd_fo02_d_000.jpeg` to the `ddd`
- `lll_fo01_l_001.jpeg` and `l_fo02_l_000.jpeg` to the `lll`

Comment: The structure you describe is the desired structure or the existing structure?

Comment: @Arcege thanks for your comment. It is the current structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```bash
for x in ccc/*; do
  [ -f "$x" ] || continue                  # skip directories in ccc
  y=${x#*_}                                # strip the ccc_ prefix
  cp -p ddd/*/ddd_"${y/_c_/_d_}" ddd/      # copy the corresponding file under ddd
  cp -p lll/*/lll_"${y/_c_/_l_}" lll/      # ditto under lll
done
```

This script assumes that you don't have e.g. `fo03` files in a `fo01` directory, or if you do have them you want to copy them anyway. If this isn't the case you may want to adjust the filename manipulation to match your exact scenario.

You may want to investigate [bash's parameter expansion features](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it but I get this error: `cp: cannot stat ddd/*/ddd_fo01_l_003.png: No such file or directory`  the `l_003` should be `d_003`